# Tool for converting an XSD to EBNF?

Tags: xsd, ebnf

Does anyone know of a tool that will take an XSD file as input and produce EBNF?

Comment: Would you mind telling me what problem you would like to solve by doing this, as there might be an easier way.

Comment: @andre:Building an interface to an existing system that uses XML to represent a domain specific language. Wanted to use non-XML representation of the language. Ended up doing it by hand.